# Can't change input Value in Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2, xcode10.1

I have an input `UITextField` and want to change his value.

I defined this `UITextField` like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var valueInput: UITextField!
```

Than in `viewDidLoad()` I make `delegate` - `self`:

```
valueInput?.delegate = self
```

and then in `viewDidLoad` I try to assign value to input like this:

```
if let priceIn = self.valueIn Input {
    valueIn.text! = strPr // (this is var and it has String format I've checked it, and I also try to make print(strPr) and I get a value)
}
```

Unfortunately this string is not working:

```
valueIn.text! = strPr
```

But if I write something like this

```
valueIn.text! = "11"
```

This one will work.

I've tried to to something like this also, but it's not working also:

```
valueIn.text! = "\(strPr)"
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for any answer, hope somebody had the same problem and know how to resolve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Do you get a compile time error? What is the type of `valueIn`?

Comment: `self.valueIn Input` — what does it even mean? It is not valid Swift.

Comment: Show the code where `strPr` is declared and populated – by the way please use more descriptive variable names. I guess it's a timing/asynchonous issue. And if you mean `if let priceIn = self.valueInput` this optional binding is pointless because the outlet is connected reliably before `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: Yes `print(strPr`) before `valueIn.text! = strPr`

Comment: Delete this line `if let priceIn = self.valueIn Input {`

Comment: You need to update the question with related things like what is "Input"? Why you define property "valueInput" and then later you want to change property "valueIn"?

Comment: Type of valueIn is String @DanielT.

Comment: @VitaliyMckay What do you mean by "it's not working"? Do you get a compile error?

Comment: @Daniel T. no, there are no compile error, it's just didn't set any value in input from my var, but if it will be any string like "hello" - it will set this one.

Comment: All because its not coming inside `if let priceIn = self.valueIn Input {
    valueIn.text! = strPr
}` The question is what's wrong with `if let priceIn = self.valueIn Input`.

Comment: @canister_exister any ideas what can it be?

Answer (score 0):

These lines are wrong:

```
valueIn.text! = strPr
valueIn.text! = "11"
```

`valueIn.text!` should only appear on the right side, in case you are sure valueIn references a valid object (not nil) and text is declared as `var text: String?`

Not sure exactly how your variables are declared, but try something like this:

```
valueIn.text = "11"
```

Or, if strPtr is an Optional, try this:

```
if let strPr = strPr {
  valueIn.text = strPr
  print("New valueIn.text: \(valueIn.text!)")
}
```

Comment: I have an error on the first line, it says "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'"

Comment: @VitaliyMckay Remove the if let strPtr = strPtr { and last } then